# «Не» или «ни» в предложении?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

*Помнишь на той регулировали сцепление? Вот это и есть рабочий, на этой коробке я ни знаю как регулировка делается, надо смотреть.                                  Да конечно, я бы просто так ни поехал.*

Подскажите, мне кажется, что вместо "ни" должно быть "не"?

Answer (score 3):

Вам правильно кажется: вместо частицы *ни* должна быть ***не***.
[**Не**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5) — частица, выражает полное отрицание того, что обозначает слово или сочетание, перед которым она стоит. *Не знаю, не умею, не помню.*

Дополнительно, конечно же, надо поставить запятые.

• ***Помнишь,** на той регулировали сцепление?*
Это сложное предложение, в котором нет подлежащих, но они подразумеваются.
([Ты] Помнишь, на той [мы, вы, они] регулировали сцепление?)
*Помнишь, на той неделе студенты приходили?* (Н. Назаркин).

• *Вот это и есть рабочий, на этой коробке я **не** знаю, **как** регулировка делается, надо смотреть.*

> **Примечание 1.** Если главное предложение находится внутри придаточного (в разговорном стиле речи), то запятая обычно ставится только после главного предложения, а перед ним не ставится, например: *Хозяйством нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался...* (Гоголь) (ср.: *Нельзя сказать, чтобы он занимался хозяйством*)...

• ***Да,** конечно, я бы просто так **не** поехал.*
Вводное слово "конечно" нуждается *в обрамлении* запятыми.
*Да, конечно, я постараюсь* (О. Новикова).
*― Да, конечно, я сам, ― твердо подчеркнул Аслан* (Ф. Искандер).

[§107. Запятая между главным и придаточным предложениями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение.